# Bind combobox-items to string resource array

Tags: c#, arrays, binding, combobox, uwp

I'm trying to bind string resources to a combobox in an UWP-Application.

I should persist a Language List in my App-Resources.

The list has a key (for eg. "en") and a human readable string (eg. "English")

Now I want to bind these values to a ComboBox and let the user select the language.

I can't find a way to do this

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show anything because I cant even create string arrays in the String resources... please tell me I'm wrong

Comment: I thought this would be an easy problem to solve but unfortunately it's not possible to bind a resource-array (which seems not existing) to a combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed not directly store an array in string resources. You could of course store a comma separated string and break it up with `string.Split`, but that get's ugly pretty fast. You can however store array items as individual string resources.

The way I do this usually is as follows.

First, create string resources that follow a naming convention, for example `Language.<isocode>`:

```
<data name="Language.EN" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>English</value>
</data>
<data name="Language.FR" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>French</value>
</data>
```

Then you can get these resources from a language identifier as follows:

```
string name = resourceLoader.GetString("Language/" + identifier.ToUpperInvariant());
```

That should allow you to build your array. Let's say you have

```
private static readonly string[] supportedLanguages = { "EN", "FR" };

public class Language
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can build the array to bind to as follows:

```
var languages = (from language in supportedLanguages
                 select new Language
                 {
                     Id = language,
                     Name = resourceLoader.GetString("Language/" + language)
                 }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for ÿour code. It's hard for me to explain it. I need something to wrap all your "<data name="Language." Tags so I can tell the ComboBox it should have all these values as Items in it. For example in android you can create string-arrays and bind them to a ComboBox. The goal is to show a ComboBox where the User can select the language of an object which he is creating